# Is django-reversion compatible with django-hstore fields?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-reversion, django-hstore

I'm curious to know if anyone else has come across this situation:

I've got a django model with a standard `CharField` and an [hstore field](http://djangonauts.github.io/django-hstore/):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    data = hstore.DictionaryField()
```

When I save changes to `MyModel`, the `name` is correctly tracked via django-reversion but `data` is not (i.e., when I revert to an old version, the name is correctly reverted but the data remains the most current version).

Comment: does hstore return any records of data ?

Comment: Yes - hstore always returns the most current record; so if I save data, then make a change, then revert - it still returns the most recent change, not the original.